# Z-Index with Sibling's Child

Tags: html, css, z-index

If I have

```
<div class="above-header">SOME STUFF</div>
<header>
    <div class="inside-header">SOME MORE STUFF</div>
</header>
```

and `inside-header` is `position: absolute` with `z-index: 1`, and `above-header` is `position: relative` with `z-index: 10`, why is `inside-header` appearing above `above-header`?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index

Comment: Could you please provide a demo (http://jsfiddle.net) and/or your CSS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because .inside-header is a child of header and is positioned absolute in header. so you need to make header position: absolute with z-index: 1